# Self Heating in Platinum Resistance Thermometers

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

In order to use a PRT a small excitation current has to be passed through it, which creates a heating effect that in turn adds an error to the measured temperature.

The question is this: If we have attached the PRT to a heatsink whose temperature we wish to measure, will the temperature error due to self heating be constant over all temperatures (assuming infinite heat sink capacity)?

Comment: Hmmm... 150uA of excitation current into a 100Ohm thermometer, that's 2.25uW... unless you are working with a really tiny thermal mass that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: I am resolving to sub milliK values. So not sure whether I will be getting a constant offset, or a more complicated relationship over the temperature range. There are also two thermal masses to worry about - the heatsink (whose temp I am measuring) and the mass/conductivity of the PRT itself

For reference, I have seen figures that indicated 200mK offset at a given temperature for a current of 1mA

Comment: Why would you use 1mA of current? That's way too much. At 390uV/mK and 100uA you are getting 39nV/mK of signal, which is over 20dB SNR, unless you need a large measurement bandwidth? Or... you just trust the manufacturer documentation which explicitly says that you won't get an appreciable measurement error due to heating if you run the device at the calibration current. Having said that, I wouldn't trust that and implement my own drift calibration.